# Question about optional binding of model struct in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I encountered this error while writing the code.

```
Expression pattern of type 'BookArr?' cannot match values of type 'BookArr?'
```

code!!

```
func infiniteScrolling(_ genre: BookArr?, _ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch genre {
    case booksGenre: return callNextBookDefault() //error!!!
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you are seeing. Please fix your example by telling us what is the declaration of `booksGenre` and either give a return type to `infiniteScrolling` or deleting `return` from before  `callNextBookDefault()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mentioned the return type of function `infiniteScrolling`. So the compiler complaining that you can't set return anything from `infiniteScrolling` function as you did not set its return type.

Either you need to remove `return` from `infiniteScrolling` method

```
func infiniteScrolling(_ genre: BookArr?, _ indexPath: IndexPath) {
  switch genre {
  case booksGenre: callNextBookDefault()
  }
}
```

or you need to specify the return type of the `infiniteScrolling` function.

```
func infiniteScrolling(_ genre: BookArr?, _ indexPath: IndexPath) -> <ReturnType> {
  switch genre {
  case booksGenre: return callNextBookDefault() 
  }
}
```

`callNextBookDefault` functions's return type should be same as `<ReturnType>`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as asked. The error message would be different if this was the problem (it is a problem, but not the one being asked about).

Comment: The code posted in question, caleb added comment on the line which causes error.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you returning anything? When function is not supposed to.

```
return callNextBookDefault()
```

If you just want to call function, remove return.

Comment: This is almost certainly not the answer to the question asked. It is an error, but not the right one.

Comment: Sometimes error is misleading. The return is certainly wrong. Let him remove it. He might get away with the error. As he is getting the error on same line.